# WP7 app version

Tags: windows-phone-7, manifest

A Windows Phone 7 app, it seems, has two places with version number - one in AssemblyInfo.cs (via `AssemblyVersion`/`AssemblyFileVersion` attributes), the other is WMAppManifest.xml. Those two seem uncorrelated - changing one does not affect the other. The Marketplace, it seems, uses the one from the manifest - can someone please confirm this?

The real question is - how do I retrieve the one from manifest programmatically to display on the About screen?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The WmAppManifest.xml number is in use. First two digits are relevant for Marketplace (it is checked when you do the update) next two are for your internal usage.

This is a regular XML file, open it as a XDocument and parse it. [An example](http://www.sevensteps.com/easy-access-to-wmappmanifestxml-app-properties-like-version-and-title.ashx).

EDIT: the example is extraneous. For just the version, use:

```
string Version = XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml")
    .Root.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks. "First two" and "next two" - what do you mean? In the manifest there's only `Version`, `AppPlatformVersion` is something completely different.

Comment: Version="1.3.0.0" 1.3 is valid for the marketplace 0.0 is for you only

Comment: The relevant info is that the manifest goes to the device as is (unprocessed), and is easily available as an XML file in run-time. That is not an immediately obvious design.

Comment: This line of code just might have saved me hours! It works with Unity, just in case anyone requires it.

Answer (score 1):

To get App Version from "WMappManifest.xml", this solution might be a bit more efficient than lukas solution:

For WP7:

```
var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver()
};
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("WMAppManifest.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("App");
    return xmlReader.GetAttribute("Version");
}
```

For WP8:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("WMAppManifest.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string appVersion = XElement.Load(stream).Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think efficiency matters much for the About screen.

Comment: I don't think the answer was specific to the About screen, but specific to how to get Version number.