# Getting Application Version Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm following the sample code on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.id.aspx) to get the current application version in C#

```
 string buildVersion = Package.Current.Id.Version.Build.ToString();
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
'Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'
```

anyone know how I can get the app version number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That API isn't available: if you look closely at MSDN you'll see that this throws an exception for WP8. You'll have to use the same techniques as for WP7.x.

Namely:

1. Look up the version number in the manifest.
2. Look up the version of an assembly.
3. Wire up a build number of your own.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680679/694641, [WP7 - get compile/build date from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4478606/694641).

Answer (score 0):

for  windows  phone  8 ..this   works..

```
String version= XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml").Root.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Val‌​ue;
```