# WP8 Get current App Version

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, xamarin

I'm currently trying to get my app current version value via code. On MSDN is shown to use the property Id of the class Windows.ApplicationModel.Package:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.id.aspx

Unfortunately it seems that the property "Id" is not implemented in WP (it throws a "not implemented exception")

Is this API really supported on WP8 or maybe WP8.1? It works only for "store apps" (released)? Anyone have used it already?

I know I can parse the WMAppManifest.xml to get a value, but I need to accomplish this from an external assembly (a custom .dll), not the app assembly.

thanks
F

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to get the `version` like this:

```
string Version = XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml")
                .Root.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
```

A better reference would be this:

[Getting Application Version Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578663/)

Comment: I've read about this solution, as I wrote. I really don't like this approach. What if MS change the way WMAppManifest is structured? More over I need to read the file from an external assembly (a referenced dll). Others suggest to check for the "calling assembly" version, which seems to be solid as solution.